# Mysqli Prepare statement not working

Tags: php

I am getting the following error when attempting to execute a prepared statement using MySQLi.

Any help to determine what I am doing incorrectly would be GREATLY appreciated.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in etc.

I am connecting properly using this statement:

```
<?php
$DBHost = "localhost";
$DBUser = "xxxxxx";
$DBPass = "xxxxxx";
$DBName = "creati38_chicos";
$dbconn = new mysqli($DBHost, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);
// check connection
if ($dbconn->connect_error) {
//echo $dbconn->connect_error;
die('Sorry, we are having some problems right now. Please check back later.'); 
}
else{
echo "You have connected Successfully";
}
?>
```

I am then using this statement:

```
<?php
if ((isset($_POST["update"])) && ($_POST["update"] == "Update Appliance")) {

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE appliances SET
    category = ?,
    make = ?,
    model = ?, 
    description = ?, 
    price = ? 
    WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssdi',
    $_POST['category'],
    $_POST['make'],
    $_POST['model'],
    $_POST['description'],
    $_POST['price'],
    $_POST['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

}
 ?>
```

Comment: Well, the error tells you all: `$mysqli` is not an object. Most likely your connection cannot be established or the variable does not exist, because of the connection getting setup in a different script apparently. Actually you just use the wrong name... Use `$dbconn` instead...

Comment: Seems like two files are different , are you including the above on your below code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not `$mysqli->prepare(` in your case it is `$dbconn->prepare(`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing

```
$dbconn = new mysqli($DBHost, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);
```

and using as

```
$mysqli->prepare()
```

make both same

Comment: why does you have -1  :| I got exactly the same analyse ... minus me too please and EXPLAIN :)

Comment: dont worry about -1 . But yes I would love to know why downvote. If I did something wrong please correct  me.

Answer (score 0):

Use **$dbconn** instead of **$mysqli**

```
$stmt = $dbconn->prepare("UPDATE appliances SET
    category = ?,
    make = ?,
    model = ?, 
    description = ?, 
    price = ? 
    WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssdi',
    $_POST['category'],
    $_POST['make'],
    $_POST['model'],
    $_POST['description'],
    $_POST['price'],
    $_POST['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

}
 ?>
```